# How to apply new class for objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am using an array that has some objects in JavaScript, which is then displayed onto an HTML element, and this works. I would like to know how I can change the class if the team WON a match and changes the class if the team LOST a match.

I am using classList.add within an If/Else statement, but this does not seem to work, as it makes the colour of all the objects Red.

Below is my HTML code and JavaScript code.

HTML:

```js
var guide = [{
    result: "won",
    match: "England 2-1 Belgium",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "England 0-1 Denmark",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 3-0 Republic of Ireland",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "Belgium 2-0 England",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 4-0 Iceland",
  }
]

var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i < guide.length; i++) {
  text += guide[i].match + "<br>";

  if (guide[i].result == "won") {
    document.getElementById("scores").classList.add('colourGreen');
  } else if (guide[i].result == "lost") {
    document.getElementById("scores").classList.add('colourRed');
  }
}

document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div class="form-guide">
  <div class="england-form-guide" id="englandFormGuide">
    <p class="scores" id="scores"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding classes to your top parent element witch will color all inside.

Instead add span with name of class right before adding the element:

```js
var guide = [{
    result: "won",
    match: "England 2-1 Belgium",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "England 0-1 Denmark",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 3-0 Republic of Ireland",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "Belgium 2-0 England",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 4-0 Iceland",
  }
]

var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i < guide.length; i++) {
  
  if (guide[i].result == "won") {
    text += '<span  class="colourGreen">' + guide[i].match + '</span><br>';

  } else if (guide[i].result == "lost") {
    text += '<span class="colourRed">' + guide[i].match + '</span><br>';

  }
}

document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.colourGreen{
color:green}

.colourRed{
color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="form-guide">
  <div class="england-form-guide" id="englandFormGuide">
    <p class="scores" id="scores"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all of the matches are inside the same `p`, so you are targeting just one HTML tag. There are many ways to solve this, but my proposed solution is to wrap each match into a span and apply the colour class as the following:

```js
var guide = [{
    result: "won",
    match: "England 2-1 Belgium",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "England 0-1 Denmark",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 3-0 Republic of Ireland",
  },
  {
    result: "lost",
    match: "Belgium 2-0 England",
  },
  {
    result: "won",
    match: "England 4-0 Iceland",
  }
]

var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i < guide.length; i++) {
  text += "<br>";

  if (guide[i].result == "won") {
    text += "<span class='colourGreen'>" + guide[i].match + "</span>";
  } else if (guide[i].result == "lost") {
    text += "<span class='colourRed'>" + guide[i].match + "</span>";
  }
}

document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div class="form-guide">
  <div class="england-form-guide" id="englandFormGuide">
    <p class="scores" id="scores"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result has only one `p` element and then just strings and `<br>` elements and you cannot style text nodes. Instead you could create new `p` element for each array element and apply class.

```js
var guide = [{"result":"won","match":"England 2-1 Belgium"},{"result":"lost","match":"England 0-1 Denmark"},{"result":"won","match":"England 3-0 Republic of Ireland"},{"result":"lost","match":"Belgium 2-0 England"},{"result":"won","match":"England 4-0 Iceland"}]

const parent = document.getElementById("scores");

guide.forEach(({ result, match }) => {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.textContent = match;
  el.classList.add(result === 'won' ? 'colourGreen' : 'colourRed')
  parent.appendChild(el)
})
```

```css
.colourGreen {
  color: green;
}

.colourRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-guide">
  <div class="england-form-guide" id="englandFormGuide">
    <p class="scores" id="scores"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```